# How to create a new dichotomized columns from values in an existing column using pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
ID       type       period
1        2          3
1        2          3
1        3          3
2        2          3
2        3          2
2        3          2
3        2          2
```

There are a total of X types and X periods. Not all types/periods will be used, but I need columns to be created for all X of each just so that the table doesn't break in the database when imported from pandas. (Assume X in this example is 3, but it's really 9, just shortened in this example.)

For each ID, I need a 0 to show if that type/period was present, and a 1 to show if it was not.

The desired dataframe looks like this:

```
ID   type_1   type_2   type_3   period_1   period_2   period_3
1    0        1        1        0          0          1
2    0        1        1        0          1          1
3    0        1        0        0          1          0
```

Any advice towards the right direction would be greatly appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: There aren't any values with 1 for type or period, how come do you need them in the output? Also, what if another number is missing in type or period columns, i.e. 4, would you want a column type_4 and period_4 in your output? Is there a specific number of types / periods you want to include in the outputs?

Comment: We have a fixed number of columns in the actual table to accommodate all possible values -- this is a new dataset so we haven't used all the possible values yet (it will eventually use them, but not for several months/years), so we still want it to output the same number of columns since it's a fixed SQL statement. And yes, if we had another missing number in type/period columns, we would still want it in the output for the same reason.

Comment: Okay thanks. And the numbers that you wish to cover range from 0 to 9, right? I assume this because you said "Assume X in this example is 3, but it's really 9"

Comment: Correct, I assume the solution would also allow us to add more if we decided to create more columns in the future (the idea is less columns than the target would break the code, but more columns will not, since the SQL would simply ignore extraneous columns at least until we add it in, but it would not ignore missing columns as that would error out). Also the number of types and periods need not be the same, they could differ over time (e.g., maybe have 11 types and 12 periods, etc.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your `DataFrame` :

```py
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> from io import StringIO

>>> df = pd.read_csv(StringIO("""
ID       type       period
1        2          3
1        2          3
1        3          3
2        2          3
2        3          2
2        3          2
3        2          2"""), sep='       ')
>>> df
    ID  type    period
0   1   2       3
1   1   2       3
2   1   3       3
3   2   2       3
4   2   3       2
5   2   3       2
6   3   2       2
```

We can use `groupby` on columns 'ID' and 'type' to extract their `size`, then `unstack` the result, fill NaNs with zeros and finally convert it to `bool` and `int` as you want `0` and `1` values :

```py
>>> df.groupby(['ID','type']).size().unstack(fill_value=0).astype(bool).astype(int)
type    2   3
ID      
1       1   1
2       1   1
3       1   0
```

And for the `period` column :

```py
>>> df.groupby(['ID','period']).size().unstack(fill_value=0).astype(bool).astype(int)
period  2   3
ID      
1       0   1
2       1   1
3       1   0
```

Comment: Thank you, this got me what I needed! I knew it was simpler than what I was trying to do! I simply concatenated values with the col name to ensure the result was consistent with what I need, then looped thru the col names afterwards and inserted new columns full of 0's to ensure the columns exists for the SQL afterwards. :)